# FragmentPagerAdapter - avoid recreation of fragments' views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I noticed that when using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` the Fragments that are non-adjacent to the current one are having their views destroyed (and their `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods called, and strangely `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` isn't being called), and `onCreateView` is being called again for these Fragments. My problem is that I have some `Timer`s running on these Fragments, and recreating them isn't viable because these timers should fire and update the relevant fragment UI. For large screens I used a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` and it works flawlessly.

The relevant code in my Activity:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return mAddNewScenesFragment; 
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return mGlobalEventsFragment;
        } else {
            return mSceneFragments.get(position - 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSceneFragments.size() + 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "New scene"; 
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return mGlobalEventsFragment.getTitle();
        } else {
            return mSceneFragments.get(position - 2).getTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

The fragments are created on the Activity's `onCreate` method and others can be added to the list at runtime, but even without adding new ones, the third fragment is destroyed when I scroll to the first one.

Is there a way to avoid their destruction or should I just forget about `ViewPager` and use a `HorizontalScrollView` for small screens too? I choose to use it because I think the "fixed" behavior really helps with usability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following method should prevent the fragments from destroying:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_fragments_to_be_kept_offscreen);
```

Comment: It is not mFragmentPagerAdapter.setOffscreenPageLimit( ) . It's mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfFragments). I'm surprised so many upvoted the mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of hacking `FragmentPagerAdapter` , simply use `ViewPager` .

```
int limit = myPagerAdapter.getCount();
// Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend from FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. 
The method onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) should not be called a second time anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The you need to set limit to pager to avoid view destroy.

```
your_pager_obj.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_fragments_on_each_side_of_the_current_fragment);
```